# Understanding Grails' GORM nested fields and performance

Tags: sql, grails, orm, grails-orm

I'm trying to understand the implications of seemingly innocent nested field access of domain objects in Grails. For example, if I have something like:

```
def blah = SomeDomain.findAllBySomething("a")
```

And then access nested fields of other domain objects, like:

```
// do stuff with blah, then grab this
def dataOfInterest = blah.findAll { it.something.that.is.nested.deep > 2 }
```

Is GORM smart at all about getting at 'deep'? Does it have to execute SQL statements and populate each object along the way? Am I correct in thinking that this is going to be terribly inefficient, and if so, with performance in mind, what might you suggest?

Comment: If the nested object is not also a domain object, you may want to rethink your data model.

Comment: Say they are all domain objects. I would imagine just getting blah does not populate the entire chain.

Comment: In this case, it absolutely will. In the example code you provided, all of this code would be running inside the scope of a GORM or Hibernate "session", probably even a transaction. As such, regardless of whether the associated objects are loaded lazily or eagerly, they will all be populated (and attached).

Comment: Think about how you would get the data using SQL, and create a query (e.g. criteria with projections, or HQL, or even SQL) that gives you just that data without unnecessarily pulling in a lot of other data that will only be discarded. Turn on SQL logging to give yourself an idea of how (in)efficient each approach is.